# Merge two columns, set value based upon original

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a data.frame looking like this:

```
date1                  date2
2015-09-17 03:07:00    2015-09-17 11:53:00
2015-09-17 08:00:00    2015-09-18 11:48:59
2015-09-18 15:58:00    2015-09-22 12:14:00
2015-09-22 12:14:00    2015-09-24 13:58:21
```

I'd like to combine these two into one column, something like:

```
dates
2015-09-17 03:07:00    
2015-09-17 11:53:00
2015-09-17 08:00:00    
2015-09-18 11:48:59
2015-09-18 15:58:00    
2015-09-22 12:14:00
2015-09-22 12:14:00    
2015-09-24 13:58:21
```

Please note that dates (like the last but one and the last but two) can be equal. Now I'd like to add a column 'value'. For every date that has it's origin in date1, the value should be 1, if it's origin is in date2, it should be 2.

Adding a new column is obvious. Merging works fine. I've used:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df$date1)
df <- data.frame(date1 = c(df$date1, test$date2 ))
```

That works perfectly fine for the merging of the columns, but how to get the correct value for df$value?

The result should be:

```
dates                  value
2015-09-17 03:07:00    1
2015-09-17 11:53:00    2
2015-09-17 08:00:00    1
2015-09-18 11:48:59    2
2015-09-18 15:58:00    1
2015-09-22 12:14:00    1
2015-09-22 12:14:00    2   
2015-09-24 13:58:21    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to mock your problem.
If you are not concerned about time complexity, this is the simplest solution that I can suggest.

```
a = c(1,3,5)
b = c(2,4,6)

df = data.frame(a, b) 
d1 = c()
d2 = c()

for(counter in 1:length(df$a))
{  
  d1 = c(d1,df$a[counter],df$b[counter]) 
  d2 = c(d2,1,2) 
}

df = data.frame(d1, d2) 
print(df)
```

> Input:
>
> a b
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 6
>
> Output:
>
> d1 d2
>
> 1  1
>
> 2  2
>
> 3  1
>
> 4  2
>
> 5  1
>
> 6  2

Comment: Oh! Combining two columns indeed takes row per row, so the value is alternating 1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2. That's it. Thanks for this wake up call ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this?

```
dates1 <- data.frame(dates = c("2015-09-17 03:07:00",
                          "2015-09-17 08:00:00",
                          "2015-09-18 15:58:00",
                          "2015-09-22 12:14:00"), value = 1)

dates2 <- data.frame(dates = c("2015-09-17 11:53:00",
                          "2015-09-18 11:48:59",
                          "2015-09-22 12:14:00",    
                          "2015-09-24 13:58:21"), value = 2)

# row-bind the two data.frames
df <- rbind(dates1, dates2)

# if "dates" is in a string format, convert to timestamp
df$dates <- strptime(df$dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# order by "dates"
df[order(df$dates),]

# result:
                dates value
1 2015-09-17 03:07:00     1
2 2015-09-17 08:00:00     1
5 2015-09-17 11:53:00     2
6 2015-09-18 11:48:59     2
3 2015-09-18 15:58:00     1
4 2015-09-22 12:14:00     1
7 2015-09-22 12:14:00     2
8 2015-09-24 13:58:21     2
```

Comment: If this would be my total list, it would, but it's likely that I will get more lines of dates.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more clever solution, but I'd just separate each column into its own data frame, add a `value` column, and then `rbind()` into a single `dates` data frame.

```
df1 <- df$date1
df1$value <- 1

df2 <- df$date2
df2$value <- 2

dates <- rbind(df1,df2)
```